# Searching for Iframe Cross domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to get change the url of a iframe(opened from MVC view) that has a domain url of a another web site within it.  When I try to retrieve the iframe object, I can't get it.  Here's the different ways I've tried. Ultimately, I just want to change the iframe's url when it's closed.

Update: When I try to get the iframe using the passed url, I get a "permission denied" error in the debugger for the iframe.

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-dialog-titlebar-close', function () {
    var id = 'frame1';
    var iframe = document.frames ? document.frames[id] : document.getElementById(id);
    var x = document.getElementById(id);
    var z =  $(id);

    //doAlert();
});

 @using (Html.BeginActionLinkDialog(new DialogOptions()
                                            {
                                                OpenURL = @Model.TitleManagerURL,
                                                OpenDialogWithIFrame = true,
                                                Title = "Title Manager",
                                                Resizable = true,
                                                Height = "500",
                                                Width = "1200",   

                                                TargetDialogId = "xx"
                                            }, new { @id = "id1", @class = "edition_sub_link" }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to change the iFrame URL on click event..

Your iFrame:

```
<iframe id="iframeLanding" width="100%" scrolling="no" height="500px"  > </iframe>
```

Here menus just for e.g. (it could be anything) with different domain URLs:

```
<Div>
 <a href="https://www.google.com" class='menu' />
 <a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com" class='menu' />
</Div>
```

Code to update the iFrame URL and resizing the same.

```
 $(document).on('click', '.menu', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var url = $(this).attr("href");
   $('#iframeLanding').attr('src', url);
   setTimeout("iframeLoad()", 3000);
});

function iframeLoad(){
  resizeIFrame();
  $("#iframeLanding").load(reSizeIFrame);
}

function resizeIFrame() {
  try {
     var helpFrame = jQuery("#iframeLanding");
     var innerDoc = (helpFrame.get(0).contentDocument) ? helpFrame.get(0).contentDocument : helpFrame.get(0).contentWindow.document;
                     helpFrame.height(innerDoc.body.scrollHeight + 35);
      } catch (e) { var g = 1; }
 }
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I left out of the fact that I'm using a Dialog to do the popup.